# How to tell if buck converter outputs are isolated?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, isolated

I'm looking for a cheap CC CV buck converter with separate grounds.

How can I determine which converters have isolated outputs and how can I find such modules?

I know sites like ebay and the likes are not very well tolerated for sourcing electronics parts, but I'm looking for a ~$5 solution and I'm definitely not going to find one at a *reputable* source.

Comment: What's the input voltage, output voltage, and maximum power draw?

Comment: @JonathanS. input 12V, output 5V, as high current as possible but for a low price of around $5 I'm hoping at best 3 to 5A...

Comment: An example part that would fit: Mornsun URB2405LD-30WR3

Answer (score 2):

A buck converter is per definition not isolated.

For the broader term of converter being able to down-regulate but with transformer (and transformer ratio), it would be a *forward* type converter.